# Filtering out N/A so that all columns beside N/A and N/A can be removed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a set of data where we need to remove the `#N/A` for the table to display accurate data.  Note, that I want to remove columns to the side of this and not only remove N/A as to make data look neater.

My code below creates a filter between a set range though I am wanting to remove `#N/A` which is present in Column one.

Instead it simply puts `#N/A` in  column one instead of removing it.

```
  sht1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    sht1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        ">=-1000000000000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=1000000000000000"
    sht1.Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ''sht1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=#N/A"
```

I have tried:

```
wb1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=#N/A"
```

As well as other variations which have yet to work for me.

The below tends to work though this is entirely useless in my case as my data is very dynamic and changing constantly.

It is worth noting that this unfilters the N/A however I am yet to get this to work for a dynamic range.

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _ 
    Array("Nov 13", "Nov 13", "Today", _ 
‘’etc,,
    ), Operator:= _ 
    xlFilterValues 
End Sub 
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"
```

[imgur.com/a/TqwDz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJLAk.jpg)

Comment: Criteria1:="<>#N/A"

Comment: @QHarr  I am unsure why, but adding that seems to break my entire script.  Uh I see.   A table cannot overlap another table.  Any ideas how I can add this filter.   Though I am adding a filter not a table.  Weird.

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the cell value #N/A (replace) or the entire row that contains #N/A ?? I'm not sure what the autofilter is for.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro filtering the table in question? Take the main components of that and substitute the criteria I posted and see if that works?

Comment: @Mitch AS you can see in image column 1 has lots of N/A. I want to filter that out so it can remove rows with formulas and N/A and clean my sheet up

Comment: That simply makes the 1st column record #n/a for every cell in column a where I want the opposite. 
 Something like.... (for dynamic content) wb1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        Array("*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues would be nice.  The column header is Date and Time though I can't seem to get this to work..

Comment: Can you repost image but hide some rows so we can also see the headers and the location in sheet?

Comment: @QHarr Can do.  Here's the new link: https://ibb.co/mvbT7b

Comment: Is that date time column populated by a formula by the way?

Comment: @QHarr Correct, with Vlookup values hence the #N/A

Comment: could you show an example formula?

Comment: @QHarr Sure. =VLOOKUP(Q139,B$2:C$40000,1,0)  I've added a new image.  You can see here: https://imgur.com/a/TqwDz that the reason I want to filter out N/A is because by doing so I can have my data even and remove the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Btw this new info and the most pertinent image could be edited into the question so others can easily find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158766/discussion-between-tyson-dogerzonda-and-qharr).

Comment: @QHarr I have updated link and highlighted purple all data beside N/A in column 1 is useless.  You can see above purple that is relevant data as no N/A present.  The reason I want to filter out this N/A is so that I can have all relevant data and not any weird numbers or N/A.  Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: have posted some code for you to have a look at

Comment: have you actually recorded a macro for a filter that works?

Answer (score 0):

You have a formula that converts a date to one of three values: -

- `Today`
- `Tomorrow`
- Any future dates

You are seeing `#N/A` because the value does not fit into one of these three options. Possible causes for this: -

- The date field is empty
- The date is in the past
- The date is to far in the future

In comments you show the formula `=VLOOKUP(Q139,B$2:C$40000,1,0)`, I'm going to take a large assumption here and assume the following: -

- B2 is a formula `=TODAY()`
- B3 to B40000 is a formula of `=B2+1` (and onwards)
- C2 has a value of `Today`
- C3 has a value of `Tomorrow`
- C4 to C40000 is a formula of `=B4` (and onwards)

Its basically a big lookup of dates to one of these three values.

This would cause the issue, and be an amazing process of elimination and deduction on my part if I'm correct (I didn't go into the chat room).

Now *IF* the above is true I would suggest the following, change the original formula `=VLOOKUP(Q139,B$2:C$40000,1,0)` to `=IF(Q139=TODAY(),"Today",IF(Q139=TODAY()+1,"Tomorrow",IF(Q139>TODAY(),Q139,"Discount")))`

This new formula states: -

- If `Q139` equals today, output `Today`
- If `Q139` equals today + 1, output `Tomorrow`
- If `Q139` is greater than today, output `Q139`
- Else output 'Discount'

You could then filter by `Discount`.

Would this work, was I even close?

Comment: What an excellent explanation of the issue and a fix, based on assumption, which I think is right on the money. The only caveat may be a cell missing a value completely, which I believe results in the same error. (I'm a novice, so not absolutely sure) I'm voting your answer up due to the quality. I found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple routine that will achieve the desired results.

```
Sub test2()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
   If IsError(c) Then
     Rows(c.Row).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
Next c
End Sub
```